# JavaFX scrollpane never scrolls

Tags: java, javafx-8

In JavaFX I have something like this:

```
VBox centreBox = new VBox();
ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(centreBox);
mainHBox.getChildren().add(scrollPane);
```

And then when the user clicks on a button, there is an action that gets triggered:

```
button.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
    for(Object obj : list) {
        HBox box = ...; // here I create a box based on obj
        centreBox.getChildren().add(box);
    }
});
```

The issue is that the `list` is quite long and ends up extending the height of `centreBox` beyond the size of the window. However, the scrollbars never get triggered.

I tried setting the scroll bar policy to always, however the bars always remain at 100% of the height (i.e. can't move them). Basically the problem is that the scrollpane doesn't seem to care about the height `centreBox`.

I also tried adding a group after reading something about it on the API:

```
Group group = new Group(scrollPane);
mainHBox.getChildren().add(group);
```

But still no joy.

I think this is to do with the fact that the contents are dynamically generated. If I hardcode some elements into there from the outset it seems to work ok.

How to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I just wrote a simple program to test this, and my ScrollPane behaves properly as Nodes are added to its content.  Please edit your question and provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try:
Use ListView instead of ScrollPane.

Edit:
In order to dynamically fill the pane with the content of the list:

```
HBox box[obj] = ...; // here I create a box based on obj
```

Comment: `mainBox` is the main container which sits inside a Tab, which sits in a TabPane. Not sure why I should use a `ListView`... why doesn't the scroll pane work as expected?

Comment: This should be a comment instead of a solution.